# Is there a way to change the font and location of SpriteKit debug data?

Tags: sprite-kit

Basically what it says in the title.

Is there a way to change the font and or location of SpriteKit debug data?

The data that we set in the viewController:

```
skView.showsFPS = YES;
skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
skView.showsDrawCount = YES;
```

Comment: there is a private bool that allows you to center the debug display but that's hardly useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add such debugging information to the scene by yourself:
 https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Actions/Actions.html

*Example: Adding a Debugging Overlay* section.

Answer (score 0):

No. Those are all part of the SKView class which offers no user changeable attributes in regards to the above 3 items.